# how to create repository in github from webstorm?

Tags: github, webstorm, github-for-windows

I am trying to create a repo in github but getting an error:

```
Successfully created project '..' on github by initial push failed
```

Is this an authentication issue? how to solve?

Comment: may be the same issue as [IDEA-115764](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-115764)

Answer (score 1):

How did you create your repository? The correct way to do this from WebStorm is VCS/Import Into version Control/Share Project On Github; if you have created your repository on GitHub and now try to push to remote repository, you need to add remote repository to your local repository in command line first ("git remote add origin `https://repo`") See http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-87099